# A word for fake sympathy?

Tags: single-word-requests

To be more precise I mean a kind of mocking sympathy where the person is like "Aw. You *poor* thing.." but it's pretty sarcastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a single word with the meaning you want. A common two-word phrase for this concept is "**mock sympathy**", which often goes along with the phrase or hand gesture of "playing the world's smallest violin."

For single words, the only terms I can think of are ones that refer to sarcasm in general, rather than false expressions of *sympathy* in particular: scorn, sarcasm, mocking.

Comment: I would've tried 'pseudo-sympathy' (false sympathy) or 'quasi-sympathy' (pretended sympathy), with a preference for the latter because of the specificity of the questioner's example.

Comment: I'd be tempted to call it "mocking sympathy."

Answer (score 6):

For fake sympathy I'd suggest "Crocodile tears"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodile_tears
Wikipedia
Crocodile tears (or superficial sympathy) are a false, insincere display of emotion such as a hypocrite crying fake tears of grief. The phrase derives from an ancient belief that crocodiles shed tears while consuming their victims.

For meaning the opposite of what one is saying: "ironic"

Irony | Define Irony at Dictionary.com
dictionary.reference.com/browse/irony
Dictionary.com
Irony definition, the use of words to convey a meaning that is the opposite of its literal meaning: the irony of her reply, “How nice!” when I said I had to work all weekend.

Answer (score 2):

Is the word you're looking for '*patronizing*'?

Comment: Instead of asking another question it would be better if you could substantiate your suggestion with references.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of remark is closely associated with the term:

[***deadpan***](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/deadpan) -

> deliberately impassive in manner

I suppose the delivery can be dripping with sarcasm, but along with, "you poor thing," you could *deadpan*, "Do you think I should call an ambulance?"  So in that, light, *deadpan* is what I associate with this sort of mock sympathy.  You deliver the words, but not the emotion.

Answer (score 0):

if it's overdone (not necessarily sarcastic, but exaggerated, insincere, disgusting, fake) it could be called

- **cloying** sympathy

http://i.word.com/idictionary/cloying

Answer (score 0):

```
[Insincere.]
```

pretending to feel something that you do not really feel, or not meaning what you say.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/insincere